# How to get correcta date (from my timezone)?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to build this code that would convert my current date into a URL path:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
var day = String(d.getDate());
if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;  
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
var year = String(d.getFullYear());
var path = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/"+ year + month + day + ".html";

resolve(path);
```

When run, the code works but it sometimes returns a URL from **the following day**. I'm guessing this has to do with timezones: **my timezone is -3** and I'm guessing the code runs UTC? Does that make sense? How can I solve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The functions you're using are all based on local values so not UTC unless your system's clock is set to UTC.

Comment: Does this code run in the browser or on your server (Node.js)?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/tour.html)

`const dt = luxon.DateTime.fromObject({zone: 'America/Chicago'});`

`dt.toLocaleString();`

Answer (score -1):

You can take guesswork out of date calculation by getting UTC data. Use something like this -

```
var d = new Date();
var month = String(d.getUTCMonth() + 1);
var day = String(d.getUTCDate());
if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;  
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
var year = String(d.getUTCFullYear());
var path = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/"+ year + month + day + ".html";

resolve(path);
```

This way, all you calculations will be with respect with UTC and you'll always get exact date irrespective of your timezone or daylight saving.